# How to catch up in science specifically with Korea and Babylon in late game?

Tags: civilization-5

I was playing in King difficulty (BNW). Without pressure from wars, Korea manage to tech up to complete Manhattan project the same time as I complete Railroads tech in first tech in Modern Era. Literally I'm one era behind him.

I was not aware at that time about his ability to boost science when he completed Wonder and he got plenty of them as he tech ahead everyone as well. It might be too late to realize this. Anyway does any one has a generic answer for this situation (not specific on this game or any civ).

Comment: Not sure about V but in IV i usually save up and bribe someone to go at war with someone that needs to be slowed down. This usually has great impact on there economy and science. If nobody else cares about them being attacked you could engage into war yourself too and earn some extra diplo points for fighting the same enemy together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ways to speed up your teching:**

Establish trade routes with him for science income, pass applicable things in the UN like Scholars in residence and arts funding. Use faith to purchase great scientists and enter the rationalism tree/take science policies like workers faculties or the one that makes speis better at stealing techs.
You probably can improve your city micro and tech pathing as well.

**Ways to slow down their teching:**

Go to war with them, hire someone to go to war with them, embargo them, tamper with their religion if they have one,

That said, at high enough difficulties Korea and Babylon are going to be strong techers, and without a tech focused civ you will have trouble keeping up with them. It sounds like you are going for either a culture or diplo victory, since its peaceful and not science. In that case, you need to concentrate either on preparing a bunch of great scientists for bulbing to internet, or simply allow yourself to fall behind in tech. Being behind in tech is least important to a diplo strategy.

Comment: Maybe war is an answer to everything.

== My game scope ==

Yep, I'm going either culture or diplo victory. Taking rationalism tree now probably too late here I suppose. (Had full Liberty/Piety/Aesthetics/Commerce and few Ordered tenets)

Korean also funded a lot in culture wonders. Invested a lot on great work, so arts funding won't hurt him that much anyway. I might need to spy on him if he had potential enough production if I gonna beat him with Culture.

Comment: Overall the ideal solution to a situation like this when you want to stay peaceful is to find some warmonger like Zulu and pay him a couple GPT to go to war. It forces korea to switch from building production to units which slows him down. However, if they have nukes already its too late